# Foreach inside multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have to make a csv file that work in this way:

```
Row 1 --> Text Data 
Row 2 --> Person Information
Row 3 --> Products information
```

The Row1 and Row2 are done, I have alrady wirte the code correctly.

The **Row3** is a problem becasue need give me back a row for every products, with all their data.

How I can write the code in the way?
At moment I havw write this, but the row3 is empty.

```
$list = array (
    array ('Order id', 'Billing Name' , 'Product Title', 'Total Price' ),
    array ($order->id, $order->firstname, '', ''),   
    $listProd = array(),
  );

  $listProd = array();
  foreach ($order->products as $product) {
    $listProd = array (
        $order->id,
        '',
        $product->title,
        $cart->renderPriceAndCurrency($product->pad_price),
    );
  }

  $local_file = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    foreach ($list as $row) {
      fputcsv($local_file, $row);
  }

  rewind($local_file);
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$list = array (
    array ('Order id', 'Billing Name' , 'Product Title', 'Total Price' ),
    array ($order->id, $order->firstname, '', ''),   
    $listProd = array(), // this does __nothing__ except adding empty array to `$list`
);
```

Replace it with:

```
$list = array (
    array ('Order id', 'Billing Name' , 'Product Title', 'Total Price' ),
    array ($order->id, $order->firstname, '', ''),   
);
foreach ($order->products as $product) {
    $list[] = array (
        $order->id,
        '',
        $product->title,
        $cart->renderPriceAndCurrency($product->pad_price),
    );
}
```

Here you add **every** product item to the end of `$list` array.

Comment: Easy! thenk you @u_mulder I went in confusion with all these arrays and foreach!

Comment: Do you know way, in the CSV file I see all products duplicated? If I put 2 products I see 2 time the same row and if I put 3 products I see 3 time the same row.

Comment: I don't know why items are duplicated. Try to debug your code. Output `$list` array - if there're duplicates - then it's connected with your `foreach`.

Comment: I find the error, doesn't in the foreach. was in the $local_file foreach. Your code work so well! thank you again.